# Calculus Made Easy Exercise 10 Question 10

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

I am currently stuck on this question. The question and my steps so far are given below:

(10) Suppose it to be known that consumption of coal by a certain steamer may be represented by the formula:
$$y = 0.3 + 0.001v^3$$
where $y$ is the number of tons of coal burned per hour and v is the
speed expressed in nautical miles per hour. The cost of wages, interest on capital, and depreciation of that ship are together equal,
per hour, to the cost of 1 ton of coal. What speed will make the
total cost of a voyage of 1000 nautical miles a minimum? And,
if coal costs 10 dollars per ton, what will that minimum cost of
the voyage amount to?

I am stuck on the first part. Here are my steps so far:

Let price of one ton of coal $= c$
wages + interest + depreciaition = T
According to the question: $T \times t = c$
If distance = 1000, $v = \frac{1000}{time}$

basically $y = \frac{tonnes}{time}$ so :
$$\frac{tonnes}{time} = 0.3 + 0.001\frac{1000^3}{time^3}$$
I solved this equation but the wring answer for v. I also do not think I am doing it right.

Please do not give away the answer but guide me in the right direction.

Many thanks and stay safe!!

Comment: So far all you've shown is how you restated the problem. What did you do next? And after that? And after that, etc., to finally reach the wrong answer for $v$ (which was what)?

Comment: Note, however, that wages + interest + depreciation **per hour** equals the cost of one ton of coal. If $T$ is wages + interest + depreciation **per hour**, and $t>1,$ then $T\times t > c$ because $T\times t$ is the cost for more than just one hour. And if $T$ is **not** wages + interest + depreciation **per hour**, what is it?

Comment: @DavidK Re your first comment, good point, but partly my fault.  Apparently, without showing his work, the OP explored the idea in my (originally wrong) analysis and (naturally enough) came up with a wrong answer.  See the comment that he left after my answer.

Comment: @user2661923 My fault too for missing a lot of that until after I posted (I blame a browser glitch). But I think we're asking the same thing from OP: to get guidance to a better solution, show the bad one. Then we can give pointers to where it went wrong.

Comment: @DavidK Except that the OP may well have solved the problem accurately, and merely not shown his work.  Assuming that my analysis is now correct, and assuming that the OP correctly followed my mistaken analysis before, if he repeats the method under my corrected analysis, he may well get the intended answer.  In that case, it is **game over.**

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, that is another possible outcome. Again it is a response that can be made once the OP has posted their calculations.

Comment: @DavidK I chatted with the OP privately.  In fact, he did use my corrected analysis appropriately, and therefore did get the right answer to part 1.  Then, we chatted about part 2, re the absolute cost of the voyage, assuming optimal speed.  He also completed that part.

Comment: @user2661923 Hooray! That's excellent news. This might be a good time for OP to accept your answer, signaling that they don't need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

Well, this is embarassing.  I went off the rails, and made a mistake in analysis.

I have corrected the mistake below.

---

Hint

Although your analysis was a good step in the right direction, you should capitalize on :

> The cost of wages, interest on capital, and depreciation of that ship are together equal, per hour, to the cost of 1 ton of coal.

---

**Edit**

I misinterpreted the meaning of the above constraint.  Further, there is an ambiguity here.  Are you supposed to minimize the total of [wages + interest + depreciation], or are you supposed to minimize the total of $\{$ [wages + interest + depreciation] + coal used $\}?$

Under the first interpretation, you are supposed to minimize the *time* taken for the voyage.  It is doubtful that this would be the intended solution.

Under the second interpretation, the **cost per hour** is
$(1 + y)$, rather than $y$.  I suspect that this is the *intent* of the problem.  Contrast that with the mistake that I made below, which (wrongly, indirectly) presumes that the cost per hour is $y$, instead of $(1 + y).$

---

This means that you do not need to use **any** variables other than $y$ and $v$.

Distance = rate $\times$ time.

The time for the voyage will be $[(1000)/v],$ so the amount of coal consumed will be $[(1000/v] \times y.$

Take both the first and second derivatives of the function [in the sole variable $v$] that represents the amount of coal that will be consumed on the voyage.

You want the first derivative to be zero and the second derivative to be positive.  Then, you will have identified the value for $v$ that represents the minimum value of the function.  From this, you can routinely determine the time of the voyage.

Comment: Is rate basically the velocity? Thanks

Comment: @AkashGopinath Yes, *rate*, *velocity*, and *speed* are all terms that (generally) refer to the same thing : distance divided by time.

Comment: This method gives me an answer that is different from the textbook. Is there anything I am missing? Thanks

Comment: @Thingybob In order to answer that question, I need you to either overhaul your original query or add an **Addendum** to your original query that focuses exclusively on the method provided by my answer.  When editing your query to show your work, be as careful/detailed as you can, going from one step to the next.  Then, when you have completed editing your query, if no one else steps up, leave another comment for me and I will look at your work.  You can either address the comment using the *at* sign followed by user2661923, or you can place the comment after my answer.

Comment: @Thingybob **My bad**!  I made a mistake in my analysis.  Please read my **edited** answer.

Comment: Is it then y + 1 = 0.3 + 0.001v^3   
Edit: I got the answer, many thanks!

Comment: @Thingybob No.  The way to correct my mistake is to realize that since the cost per hour is $(1 + y)$, and since you want to minimize the overall cost of the voyage, the **cost function** that you want to minimize is $$[1000/v] \times (1 + y).$$  You should convert this into a **cost function** that **only** uses the variable $v$ and then take the first and second derivatives of this *single variable* cost function.  Then, you want the first derivative $= 0$ and the second derivative positive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117403/discussion-between-thingybob-and-user2661923).